# Preserve panel size across differing numbers of panels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I want to plot two figures from different data frames and later combine them into one figure (the final figure is more complicated). Each figure  shows a subset of the data over two categorical variables (say "Sex" and "Round"). The plotted data is the same type across both figures.  Each dataset differs in the number of levels of these categorical variables.

For instance, here's mock data plotted in a 3 x 2 grid:

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(10)

# Mock data
N <- 10
rounds <- c("A", "B", "C")
NROUNDS <- length(rounds)

df1 <- data.frame(
    Age = 1:N, 
    Response = rnorm(N*2*NROUNDS), 
    Sex = rep(c("M", "F"), each = N), 
    Round = rep(rounds, each = N*2)
)

# Dimension parameters
panel_width <- 2.5
panel_height <- 1.5
ylims <- c(-4, 4)
units <- "in"
panel_spacing <- 0.1
plot_mar <- 0.25

total_x_margin <- panel_spacing + plot_mar*2
total_y_margin <- panel_spacing*(NROUNDS-1) + plot_mar*2

# Plot the figure
six_panel_plot <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = Age, y = Response)) + 
    geom_line(lwd = 2, color = "#CC79A7") + 
    facet_grid(rows = vars(Round), cols = vars(Sex)) + 
    ylim(ylims) + 
    theme(
        panel.spacing.x = unit(panel_spacing, units),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(panel_spacing, units),
        plot.margin = margin(plot_mar, plot_mar, plot_mar, plot_mar, units)
    ) + theme_bw()

# Save the figure
ggsave("six_panel_plot.png", six_panel_plot, 
    width = total_x_margin + panel_width*2, 
    height = total_y_margin + panel_height*NROUNDS)
```

[image: six_panel_plot]

I have tried to adjust the figure size based upon the number of panels in each dimension and the size of margins. However, if create a similar figure on a 4 x 2 grid the dimensions of the individual panels are not quite the same as the previous figure.

```
# Mock data
N <- 10
rounds <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
NROUNDS <- length(rounds)

df2 <- data.frame(
    Age = 1:N, 
    Response = rnorm(N*2*NROUNDS), 
    Sex = rep(c("M", "F"), each = N), 
    Round = rep(rounds, each = N*2)
)


# Dimension parameters
panel_width <- 2.5
panel_height <- 1.5
ylims <- c(-4, 4)
units <- "in"
panel_spacing <- 0.1
plot_mar <- 0.25

total_x_margin <- panel_spacing + plot_mar*2
total_y_margin <- panel_spacing*(NROUNDS-1) + plot_mar*2


eight_panel_plot <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = Age, y = Response)) + 
    geom_line(lwd = 2, color = "#CC79A7") + 
    facet_grid(rows = vars(Round), cols = vars(Sex)) + 
    ylim(ylims) + 
    theme(
        panel.spacing.x = unit(panel_spacing, units),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(panel_spacing, units),
        plot.margin = margin(plot_mar, plot_mar, plot_mar, plot_mar, units)
    ) + theme_bw()

ggsave("eight_panel_plot.png", eight_panel_plot, 
    width = total_x_margin + panel_width*2, 
    height = total_y_margin + panel_height*NROUNDS)
```

[image: eight_panel_plot]

If I align these figures in other software (Inkscape, Illustrator, etc) the panels are not the same dimensions.

How do I preserve the size of the individual **panels** across figures (without simply forcing the first figure to have four rows)?  I want to avoid using additional packages, is this possible with only ggplot2?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a ggplot-only solution, but I'll use some of the packages that ggplot itself depends on (grid & gtable), so no extra downloads needed. I've assumed the desired units were defined in inches, but it's easy to change.

```
library(grid)

# As per your post
panel_width <- 2.5
panel_height <- 1.5

# Convert plot to gtables
plots <- list(p8 = ggplotGrob(eight_panel_plot), 
              p6 = ggplotGrob(six_panel_plot))

plots <- lapply(plots, function(gt) {
  # Find the positions of panels
  panel_x <- unique(panel_cols(gt)$l)
  panel_y <- unique(panel_rows(gt)$t)
  # Change the sizes of these positions
  gt$widths[panel_x] <- unit(panel_width, "inch")
  gt$heights[panel_y] <- unit(panel_height, "inch")
  gt
})

ggsave("test1.png", plot = plots[[1]])
ggsave("test2.png", plot = plots[[2]])
```

test1.png:

[image]

test2.png:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could try egg::set_panel_size()

Comment: Please add an answer with examples. Avoid writing a single line answers